# Flask-SqlAlchemy: TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'tables'

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to add an existing MySQL database in my Flask app.

My code can be found below:

`__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import config

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    db.init_app(app)
    db.reflect(app=app)


    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    return app
```

`manage.py`:

```
from myapp import create_app
from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
manager = Manager(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

And `models.py` is:

```
from . import db, login_manager

db.Model.metadata.reflect(db.engine)

class Calls(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['Calls2']
    __bind_key__ = 'calls'

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.test1
```

However, I get this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG') or 'default')
  File "/home/ilias/client-reporting/app/__init__.py", line 49, in create_app
    db.reflect(app=app)
  File "/home/ilias/client-reporting/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 872, in reflect
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'reflect')
  File "/home/ilias/client-reporting/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 848, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), tables=tables)
  File "/home/ilias/client-reporting/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 3380, in reflect
    Table(name, self, **reflect_opts)
  File "/home/ilias/client-reporting/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 406, in __new__
    table._init(name, metadata, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/ilias/client-reporting/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 473, in _init
    self._extra_kwargs(**kwargs)
  File "/home/ilias/client-reporting/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 552, in _extra_kwargs
    self._validate_dialect_kwargs(kwargs)
  File "/home/ilias/client-reporting/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py", line 282, in _validate_dialect_kwargs
    "named <dialectname>_<argument>, got '%s'" % k)
TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'tables'
```

Comment: You're using an old version of flask-sqlalchemy. This is issue [#53](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/53).

Comment: Thanks! That worked!